# Constant `MaxNominations` is removed from the Kusama runtime starting from 9170

Tags: runtime, kusama, staking, bug

I just noticed that `staking.MaxNominations` constant is [removed](https://kusama.subscan.io/runtime/Staking?version=9170) from Kusama's runtime metadata starting from 9170. However, I did not find any proper replacement neither in constants nor in storage. Are nomination limits removed entirely or migrated to another place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this was removed accidentally in https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10601. [This PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10947) will bring it back, thanks for reporting this.